# Actualizar datos de una ArrayList

Tags: java

[image: Codigo]Si alguien me pudiese ayudar...

Estoy guardando coordenadas en tiempo real en una base de datos y, según se van almacenando (según me voy moviendo), las dibujo en el mapa mediante un marcador. Para que no se me llene el mapa de puntos, necesito que, cuando se me añada el marcador más reciente, se me borre el anterior. Y así con todos. Os dejo una captura del código.

Espero que me haya explicado bien y me podais ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola podrias explicar mejor que problema estas teniendo? Tienes problemas  de excepcion? saludos

Comment: Pega tu código directamente en el post y los errores que estás teniendo para que te podamos ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Si, perdonadme. No me da ningún error. Lo que ocurre es que el mapa se me llena de puntitos, cuando solo debería haber uno (el de la ultima ubicación). Es como si fuese el gps del movil, el puntito azul q se mueve, solo que yo lo hago con marcadores y, a medida que me muevo, cada x tiempo, se pone un marcador nuevo. Qué ocurre? Que no soy capaz a borrar los antiguos y se me llena el mapa de puntos.  Y así, al mirar el mapa a simple vista, no sé cuál es la posición actual, porque hay miles de marcadores.

Comment: Hola podrías poner el código como texto y no como imagen?

Comment: Estás usando el maps sdk para android no? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker

Comment: lo he resuelto con googleMap.clear(). Así sólo me dibuja uno. Y lo de las listas nada.